# Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka: Stop query from crashing when Kafka message doesn't match JSON schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Kinda an offshoot of a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733232/remove-corrupt-rows-from-spark-streaming-dataframe-that-dont-fit-schema-inco) I had a month ago. 
I have a spark structured steaming application that I'm reading in from Kafka. Here is the basic structure of my code.

I create the spark session.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("app_name")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Then I read from the stream

```
val data_stream = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server_list")
  .option("subscribe", "topic")
  .load()
```

In Kafka record, I cast the "value" as a string. It converts from binary to string.

```
val df = data_stream
    .select($"value".cast("string") as "json")
```

Based off of a pre-defined schema, I try to parse out the json structure into columns. However, the problem here is if the data is "bad" or a different format then it doesn't match the defined schema. I need to filter out row's that do not match my schema. Whether they are null, numbers, some random text like "hello". If it is not a json then it should not proceed through to the next dataframe process

```
val df2 = df.select(from_json($"json", schema) as "data")
  .select("data.*")
```

if I pass in an empty kafka message through console producer the Spark query crashes giving

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:420)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:417)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JsonToStruct.nullSafeEval(jsonExpressions.scala:500)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:325)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.eval(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:219)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:218)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:463)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:52)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:49)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)

Comment: You'll need to do `dropNa()` first, or otherwise call `filter()` after you parse the message before you can `select()` anything. This is one of those scenarios where using Avro w/ Schema Registry would enforce the topic to always have a parsable schema

Comment: I appreciate the response by dropNa() is not a real member of the spark sql dataframe class. Any ideas of how I could filter?

Comment: It's `na().drop()` or `dropna()` or something like that. And the documentation has fine filter examples. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@filter(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]

Comment: Cool When i searched for DropNa nothing came up, but a search for spark na.drop did thanks!